# Will mysql deadlock happen when autocommit=1 and all sql is simple enough for just CRUD one row?

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, autocommit

My database is mysql5.7, innodb, isolation level is READ COMMITTED.
I am afraid of deadlock, so I keep mysql sql statement simple, only have：

- `insert into ... where ...`
- `insert into ... where ... on duplicate key update ...`
- `update ... where ...`
- `delete from ... where ...`
- `select * from ... where ...`

Each sql will have only one statement of above. for example:
A connection exec `insert into ... where ...;` for once, never exec multi statement `insert ... where ...; update ... where ...;`
The `where` statement have unique index constraint to assure operating only one row except select.
Only the select operation will involve multi rows.
I have 64 or more mysql connections, and I separate mysql operation to assure each connection operating different row.
With the autocommit=1 configuration, will deadlock happen? If the deadlock probability is not zero, what is the scene to enter deadlock? and Why? I need help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you use `BEGIN...COMMIT`?  (We need to see the whole transaction, not the individual statements.)  How many rows are _looked at_ (not just _affected_) by a troublesome row?  What does `SHOW ENGINE=InnoDB STATUS;` say?  (Or at least the "deadlock" section.)

Comment: no use of `BEGIN ... COMMIT`, just set autocommit=1 and exec simple sql that with only one operation. Now, no deadlock happens. I want to know if deadlock will happen

Comment: If those are multi-row operations _or poorly indexed_, then deadlocks may be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your updates will use multi rows operations or you don't have proper indexes and if you are doing multiple operations on same row at a time and  then high possibilities for deadlock.

In case you see then check statement for deadlock with below command once.

> SHOW ENGINE=InnoDB STATUS;

Comment: I use unique index to assure my update using only one row. Doing multiple operations on same row? Is the `on duplicate key update` a multiple operation? Can you show some examples?

Comment: with **on duplicate key update** if new data inserts then no issue it'll perform as usual. while updating exiting row and if same time, you'll try to do some update operation on same data then possibility increase for dead lock.

Note: you'll see **2 row(s) affected** in that kind of insert.

Comment: Why 2 rows? The unique index point to only one row. How deadlock happens? I will test the `on duplicate key update` and `update` in different connections.

Comment: check if this link will help you 
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/

Comment: thank you for your help. I checked that, no deadlock will happen when isolation level is READ COMMITTED. If I set the REPEATABLE READ, and operation the same row in different connections, deadlock will happen.